# Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render

Tags: reactjs, api, mern

I'm new to react, and I'm building an app using the an unofficial harry potter api.

This is the app:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class HouseHistoryCard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      househistory: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id
    axios.get(`https://www.potterapi.com/v1/houses/${id}?key=XXXXX`)

      .then(res => this.setState({ househistory: res.data }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  CapitlizeString() {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
  }

  render() {
    console.log('char', this.state.househistory)
    return (
      <section className="single-househistory hero is-fullheight">
        <div className="tile is-ancestor">
          <div className="tile is-vertical is-4">
            <div className="tile">
              <div className="tile is-parent is-vertical">
                <article className="tile is-child notification">
                  <p className="title">School: {this.state.househistory.school}</p>
                  <p className="subtitle">Head of house: {this.state.househistory.headOfHouse}</p>
                </article>
                <article className="tile is-child notification">

                  <p className="title ">Mascot {this.state.househistory.mascot}</p>
                  <p className="title">Colors {this.state.househistory.colors}</p>

                </article>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="tile is-parent">
              <article className="tile is-child notification">

                <p className="subtitle">House Ghost {this.state.househistory.houseGhost}</p>
                <p className="subtitle">House colors: {this.state.househistory.colors}</p>          
                <div className="content">

                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="tile is-parent">
            <article className="tile is-child notification">
              <div className="content">
                <p className="title">house name {this.state.househistory.name}</p>

                <p className="title">founder: {this.state.househistory.founder}</p>
                <p className="subtitle"> House values: {this.state.househistory.values}</p>
                <div className="content">
                  <div className="tile is-parent">
                    <article className="tile is-child notification">
                      <figure className="image is-3by3">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sIuqs9a.jpg" />
                        <p className="subtitle"> {this.state.househistory.founder} founded this great house. It is said, {this.state.househistory.founder} valued {this.state.househistory.values} and wanted those who shared those values to enter their founding house.</p>
                        {/* <p className="subtitle">Hall of Fame: {this.state.househistory.members} </p> */}
                        {/* <p className="subtitle">When {this.state.househistory.name} first encountered a Boggart, it revealedtheir worst fears- {this.state.househistory.boggart}!</p> */}
                        <p className="subtitle"> {this.state.househistory.name} Hall of Fame: {this.state.househistory.members} </p>

                      </figure>
                    </article>
                  </div>
                  {/* <!-- Content --> */}
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Link to="/houses">
          <div className="box has-text-centered button is-black center">
                          Return to hogwarts history
          </div>
        </Link>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default HouseHistoryCard
```

The JSON response from the API is sucessfuly displaying when i console log, however i am having an issue rendering the output. I'm using Bulma for frontend styling.

This is in my app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import axios from 'axios'
// import Auth from './lib/auth'


import 'bulma'
import './styles/styles.scss'


import HouseHistory from './components/HouseHistory'
import HouseHistoryCard from './components/HouseHistoryCard'


const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <NavBar />

    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/houses" component={HouseHistory} />
      <Route exact path="/houses/:id" component={HouseHistoryCard} />      
    </Switch>


  </ BrowserRouter>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

This is the error message:

> backend.js:6 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
>       in p (created by HouseHistoryCard)
>       in div (created by HouseHistoryCard)
>       in article (created by HouseHistoryCard)
>       in div (created by HouseHistoryCard)
>       in div (created by HouseHistoryCard)
>       in section (created by HouseHistoryCard)
>       in HouseHistoryCard (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Route (created by App)
>       in Switch (created by App)
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in BrowserRouter (created by App)
>       in App

It's strange, as I've been using the same format for another page that fetched the data easily.. what am i doing wrong in this instance? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say. Probably one of the state values isn't what you expect it to be. What does your `console.log('char', this.state.househistory)` show?

Comment: Hi Brian, my console.log is exactly what i expect it to be- it's showing the array of information for the hogwarts house i've selected from the previous page: ```Array(1)
0:
_id: "5a05da69d45bd0a11bd5e06f"
name: "Ravenclaw"
mascot: "eagle"
headOfHouse: "Fillius Flitwick"
houseGhost: "The Grey Lady"
founder: "Rowena Ravenclaw"
__v: 0
school: "Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry"
members: Array(17)
0: {_id: "5a0fa8a6ae5bc100213c233b", name: "Terry Boot"}
1: {_id: "5a107ffee0686c0021283b21", name: "Cho Chang"}...```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't accessing the [0] index in my map- this was very early on in my react and javascript journey but i hope this helps out anyone starting out.